# How do I extract the first and last entry made by an employees during shift in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Edit: I'm very sorry for the confusion, it's clear I haven't explained it well, I need to save the first and last entry for every person for every day in my csv.

```
Basically what I have is:     


    3/4/2020 8:29   Ali             
    3/4/2020 8:35   Vlad
    3/4/2020 11:47  Vlad
    3/4/2020 11:47  Vlad
    3/4/2020 11:49  Ali
    3/4/2020 13:44  Vlad
    3/4/2020 11:49  Ali
    3/4/2020 14:15  Vlad
    3/4/2020 17:20  Ali
    3/4/2020 17:54  Vlad
    3/5/2020 07:20  Ali




And what I need is:



    3/4/2020 8:29   Ali     
    3/4/2020 17:20  Ali
    3/4/2020 8:35   Vlad
    3/4/2020 17:54  Vlad
```

Comment: What if there is only a single entry?

Answer (score 2):

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)#Coaerce Date to Datetime
df.set_index(df.Date, inplace=True)#Set Date as index
df2=df.groupby(df.Name).Date.agg(['first', 'last']).stack().reset_index()#Groupby and extract names and dates
df2.columns=['Name', 'ShiftSignIn', 'Date']
```

[image]

Comment: See my edits, I noticed that, In fact it tallies with your expected output

Comment: @Datanovice, see the users expected output please

Comment: Hmm you are right, doesn't make total sense, will wait for response

Comment: Right now it's giving me the first and last entry for in that file for all users. I need to displayed the first and last entry of the day for all users.

the output for your code is:



`0         Adrian first 2020-03-31 15:52:00
1         Adrian last 2020-05-01 07:08:00
2         Albert first 2020-04-07 22:48:00
3         Albert last 2020-04-28 07:02:00`

Comment: My code, was done to output what you had indicated as an output 24hrs ago. Has that changed? Also remember Dan has no 7.20am!

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I described it wrong. Dan has no 7 am because he's doing a night shift. That output was from a file i where i ran the snippet. 
Forgetting for a second about the night shift, based on my example, I need the first and last entry for every person for every day in my csv, so basically it would read out like this:

    3/4/2020 8:29   Ali     
    3/4/2020 17:20  Ali
    3/4/2020 8:35   Vlad
    3/4/2020 17:54  Vlad
    3/5/2020 7:22   Ali     
    3/5/2020 15:20  Ali
    3/5/2020 7:54   Vlad
    3/5/2020 18:01  Vlad

Comment: So you just changed question?

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer. Could you please click upward arrow so that someone  looking for the answer with a question like yours can confidently use your question and my solution?

Comment: could you please answer my second question?

Answer (score 0):

```
df_bydate = df.sort_values(by='DateTime',ascending=True)

df_grouped = df_bydate.groupby('DateTime')['Employee'].apply(list)

Ali_first = df_grouped["Ali"].values[0]
Ali_last = df_grouped["Ali"].values[-1]
```

I did not have the chance to try it but maybe this solves your problem. Here we first sort the table by Dates then we use groupby method to get dates related to employees grouped so every column is now an employee and every row is a date. And because of dates are sorted if you get first element of a column, you will access the first date posted by that employee.
Don't worry about night shifts since sorting by datetime should sort them in chronological order.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it's giving me 'TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer' at `Ali_first = df_grouped["Ali"].values[0]`

Comment: I will have a look but I think it is an indexing error.

Comment: if you want thousands of employees would you hard code each one?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, `groupby` `agg`, with `stack` we will use `drop_duplicates` to handle entries with only one entry per day.

```
#create helper column.
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'],format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')



df2 = df.groupby(['name',df['datetime'].dt.day])\
     .agg(first=('datetime','min'),
     last=('datetime','max')).stack().reset_index()\
    .rename(columns={'level_2' : 'status','datetime' : 'day', 0 : 'datetime'})\
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['name','datetime'],keep='first')
```

---

```
print(df2)

  name  day status            datetime
0   Ali    4  first 2020-03-04 08:29:00
1   Ali    4   last 2020-03-04 17:20:00
2   Ali    5  first 2020-03-05 07:20:00
4   Dan    4  first 2020-03-04 23:01:00
6   Dan    5  first 2020-03-05 02:01:00
7   Dan    5   last 2020-03-05 07:41:00
8  Vlad    4  first 2020-03-04 08:35:00
9  Vlad    4   last 2020-03-04 17:54:00
```

if you only want entries with a start and finish change `keep=False`

```
   name  day status            datetime
0   Ali    4  first 2020-03-04 08:29:00
1   Ali    4   last 2020-03-04 17:20:00
6   Dan    5  first 2020-03-05 02:01:00
7   Dan    5   last 2020-03-05 07:41:00
8  Vlad    4  first 2020-03-04 08:35:00
9  Vlad    4   last 2020-03-04 17:54:00
```